# Hibernate join query without direct connection

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have following entity class

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "CID")
    private String cid;
}


public class Alccs {
    @Id
    private int vid;
//    @Column(name = "CID")
//    private String cid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CID", referencedColumnName = "CID")
    private Customer customer;
}


public class Rtwo {
    @Id
    private int jobNo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CID", referencedColumnName = "CID")
    private Customer customer;
}




public class RTwoCycle {
    @Id
    private int cycleJobNo;
    @Column
    private int vid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "JobNo", referencedColumnName = "JobNo")
    private TblRtwo tblRtwo;

}
```

How do I write query like following using `HQL` and `criteria`

`select top 20 * from RTwoCycle rtCycle join Alccs al on rtCycle.vid = al.vid;`

For HQL I tried following

`from TBLRTwoCycle rtCycle join TBLAL al on rtCycle.vid = al.vid`

but getting `QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!` error

and about criteria i dont know how to do it

how to do this??

Comment: did u try using nativeQuery? are you using spring-data-jpa?

Comment: i am not using spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `HQL` simple join and `on clause` is enough

`from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.vid=t2.vid`

or

`from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.vid=t2.vid`

for criteria `Restriction.sqlRestriction` is the solution for this problem

```
session.createCriteria(Class1,"c1")
        .createAlias("class2", "c2")
        .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("c1.vid=c2.vid")
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA and Hibernate versions older than 5.1 require a defined relationship to join two entities in a JPQL query. That often leads to cascading JOIN statements to traverse the relationship graph between the entities or the statement that a JOIN of the entities is not possible with JPQL if there is no relationship between them.

Hibernate 5.1 introduced explicit joins on unrelated entities. The syntax is very similar to SQL and allows you to define the JOIN criteria in an ON statement.

[More Info](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/)

Answer (score 0):

1. `from RTwoCycle as rtCycle inner join Alccs as al with rtCycle.vid = al.vid`

Comment: how to do with session.createCriteria?

Comment: While this may provide an answer to the question, it would be a lot more useful if you could give an explanation as to what the problem was and how this answer solves it.

Comment: You can't join unrelated entities with Criteria API.. Try this with hql like above.